# Devise session sharing between subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subdomain, session-cookies, docker-compose

I'm trying to share session between subdomain, but I couldn't.

I followed this [Devise config](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-subdomains), but it didn't work.

This is how my **/etc/hosts** looks like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       apedraza.bejoy.local
127.0.0.1       bejoy.local
127.0.1.1       augusto-Lenovo-G580
127.0.0.1       api.the_genesis.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and my **config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_bejoy_session', domain: ".bejoy.local"
```

In my *bejoy.local:5000/users/sign_in*, I created an account(with subdomain **apedraza**) and it redirects to *apedraza.bejoy.local:5000/admin*, but that routes redirects to *apedraza.bejoy.local:5000/users/sign_in*, that is because the session can't be found.

I have the rails app into a Docker container, so not sure if that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @iashraf for your reply.

I had already tried that, but didn't work for me.

However, after create a new rails project from scratch, I could see that config was correct.

So thanks to that, I found that the problem was on other place:
  I re-write the Registration controller for Devise, I screw it up because I used a `redirect` to a subdomain on the `super` block.

Finally, I deleted the redirect from the `super` block and put the url_path on the `after_sign_up_path_for`, and this worked!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

**config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_bejoy_session', domain: :all
```

Note in above line: `domain: :all`

(Don't forget to restart rails and clear your cookies)

Comment: Are you certain of this answer?  If not, it should have been a comment.

Comment: I think the `tld_length: 2` is missing here.